# MongoDB Custom Conversion

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In my Spring Boot application, i'm trying to retrieve a list of shops located in a certain area from a MongoDB database. These shops are in the database in this form:

```
{
   _id:ObjectId("5a0c6711fb3aac66aafe26c8")
   picture:"http://placehold.it/150x150"
   name:"Sonique"
   email:"leilaware@sonique.com"
   city:"Rabat"
   location:Object
      type:"Point"
      coordinates:Array
          0:-6.74938
          1:33.83436
}
```

The ShopEntity class where a shop is being retrieved is:

```
package com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.tech_services.persistence;

import com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.domain.model.Location;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "shops")
public class ShopEntity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String picture;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String city;
    private Location location;

    public ShopEntity() {}

    public ShopEntity(ObjectId id, String picture, String name, String email, String city, Location location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.city = city;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shop{\n" +
                "\tid: " + id + '\n' +
                "\tpicture: " + picture + '\n' +
                "\tname: " + name + '\n' +
                "\temail: " + email + '\n' +
                "\tcity: " + city + '\n' +
                "\tlocation: " + location + '\n' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

where the location class is a simple POJO:

```
package com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.domain.model;

public class Location {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public Location() {}

    public Location(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ latitude: " + latitude + ", " +
                "longitude: " + longitude + " " +
                "}";
    }
}
```

In order to convert the GeoJsonPoint location property into my custom Location object, I've made a custom converter to handle this case:

```
package com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.tech_services.persistence;

import com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.domain.model.Location;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint;

@ReadingConverter
public class GeoJsonPointToLocationConverter implements Converter<GeoJsonPoint, Location> {
    @Override
    public Location convert(GeoJsonPoint source) {
        Location location = new Location(source.getY(), source.getX());
        return location;
    }
}
```

Then i've registered this converter into the mongo configuration as below:

```
package com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.tech_services.persistence;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.CustomConversions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "shop_finder";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() {
        return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new GeoJsonPointToLocationConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working, The shops are being retrieved but the Location attribute don't get initialized with the appropriate coordinates:

```
Shop{
    id: 5a0c6b42fd3eb67969316d83
    picture: http://placehold.it/150x150
    name: Sonique
    email: leilaware@sonique.com
    city: Rabat
    location: { latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0 }
}
```

Please, what am i doing wrong!

Edit: In order to decouple the persistence layer from other layers, I've simply exposed the entities as domain classes through a facade as shown below:

```
package com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.tech_services.persistence;

import com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.domain.model.Location;
import com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.domain.model.Shop;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Circle;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@EnableMongoRepositories
@Service
public class MongoFacade {

    @Autowired
    private ShopsRepository shopsRepository;

    public List<Shop> findShopsWithin(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, double radiusInKm) {
        List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ShopEntity> shopEntities = shopsRepository.findByLocationWithin(new Circle(centerLongitude, centerLatitude, radiusInKm/111.12));
        for (ShopEntity shopEntity :
                shopEntities) {
            shops.add(new Shop(shopEntity.getPicture(), shopEntity.getName(), shopEntity.getEmail(), shopEntity.getCity(),
                    new Location(shopEntity.getLocation().getY(), shopEntity.getLocation().getX())));
        }

        return shops;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try debugging, does the control come to you GeoJsonPointToLocationConverter::convert method? Another  point. Where is GeoJsonPoint class?

Comment: The custom conversions gets effectictively registered by the customConversions() method, but it seems that GeoJsonPointToLocationConverter::convert doesn't get called!

Comment: Yes. That is because, you have declared your converter as `public class GeoJsonPointToLocationConverter implements Converter<GeoJsonPoint, Location> {
`. But what is GeoJsonPoint class ?  where is it used in ShopEntity or Location.

Comment: you converter gets called only if mongo finds an entry in database that it needs to be converted to GeoJsonPoint. This will happen only if you are using GeoJsonPoint in your entity

Comment: What motivates me in applying this conversion is to decouple other layers such as domain and presentantion layers from the persistence layer details, if i use GeoJsonPoint in ShopEntity other layers with be forced to know about GeoJsonPoint which is a persistence layer detail

Comment: Either you can have two shop models, one for other layers, one for persistent layer or  what you can do is, Use one model class and control what is being sent to other layers. If other layers are communicating through json, then you can exclude GeoJsonPoint in the json you send

Comment: I'll try to do it that way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let me add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your custom conversion is not called is because, The type(GeoJsonPoint) you have mentioned in your Conversion class is not used in your Entity (ShopEntity) class.

Mongo will call your converter(`ReadingConverter`) only when it has to convert the object in the database to the Entity type you have specified, and in the process, if it encounters the type you have specified in your Conversion class.